# Combination of std::ios::openmode to avoid modifications of an existing file?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, stream, iostream

Is there an available combination of `std::ios::openmode` to avoid modifications of an existing file and allow only the creation of a new one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. See the C++03 Standard § 27.4.2.1.4/1, or the C++11 Standard § 27.5.3.1.4/1
if to hand or otherwise http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode. As none
of the specified constants that may be |-conjoined to form an `openmode`
implies that the opened file shall *not* exist no conjunction of them can have 
that implication.

Comment: @Cubbi Why? That's just an implementation detail (and in the end doesn't tell the OP what those flags actually mean, `out|in` means `"r+"`, but what is `"r+"`?). Additional link, Ok, better link, definitely not.

Comment: @ChristianRau well, the question was about files, not streams in general. But I agree, it doesn't tell the whole story either.