# Combination of std::ios::openmode to truncate if the file exists but prevent new file creation?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, file-io, stream

I have asked earlier if [there was a combination of openmode to avoid modifications of an existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611977/combination-of-stdiosopenmode-to-avoid-modifications-of-an-existing-file). Now I would like to know if the contrary is possible :

1. if the file already exists, truncate it (`std::ios::trunc`)
2. if the file does not already exist, do nothing

Is there an `std::ios::openmode` available to do that with an `std::ofstream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no such an open mode (it does not look like a very common use case). I guess you could first check whether the file exists and, only if it does, open it with `trunc` open mode.